# Mumford's proof of theta function convergence

Tags: complex-numbers, theta-functions

On Dave Mumford's *Tate Lectures on Theta I*, he begins by proving that $\theta(z,\tau)$ converges. It begins something like:

> Let $|Im(z)|<c$ and $Im(\tau)>\epsilon$, then:
>
> $|e^{\pi i n^2 \tau + 2\pi inz}| < (e^{-\pi \epsilon })^{n^2} (e^{2\pi c})^{n}$

It is clear to me that $\displaystyle |e^{\pi i n^2 \tau + 2\pi inz}|=(e^{-\pi Im(\tau) })^{n^2} (e^{-2\pi Im(z)})^{n}$.

I understand the rest of the proof, assuming the inequality, but I don't get how he get's it in the first place. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Are you missing an $i$ somewhere? Because $|e^{2\pi n z}|=e^{2\pi n \text{Re}\, z}$ (note the real part!), assuming $n$ real.

Comment: @mickep. I'm sorry, you are right. It's fixed now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not really sure what your issue is. Maybe this:

The function $R\ni x\mapsto e^{-x}$ is decreasing. Thus, since $\text{Im}\,\tau>\epsilon$ it holds that
$$
e^{-\pi\text{Im}\,\tau}<e^{-\pi\epsilon}.
$$
Also, since $\text{Im}\,z>-c$
$$
e^{-2\pi\text{Im}\,z}<e^{-2\pi(-c)}=e^{2\pi c}.
$$